# How to determine SQL Server stored procedure parmeters at run time in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

Is there any way for an application to determine the parameters and paramter types of a stored procedure at run time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADO.Net has this functionality. You'll want to use

`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(mySqlCommand)`

This will populate your `SqlCommand` object, "mySqlCommand", with the name and type of the parameters.  However, it does require an extra call to the database.

There are a few walkthroughs on the web if you google around for them.  4Guys has one [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131038/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092408-1.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks, The 4guys link covers what Im trying to to achive, a dynamic reporting tool, based on stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

no, but you can get it from information_schema.parameters

example procedure

```
create procedure prtest
@id int,
@name varchar(200),
@value decimal(20,10)
as
select 'bla'

go
```

now run this query

```
select parameter_name,data_type,* from information_schema.parameters
where specific_name = 'prtest'
order by ordinal_position
```

output

```
@id int
@name   varchar
@value  decimal
```

you still need to get the sizes from CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using the [DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) method of the [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx) class...

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyStoredProc", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

    foreach (SqlParameter item in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ParameterName);
    }
}
```